# string split in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I want to split string between a tab.  Let's say I have some text in a file.txt

```
Kern_County_Museum  1,000,000+
Fairplex_railway_exhibit    Depot and rolling stock
```

So I want to remove redundancy from left side and keep right side as it is.

```
import re
import string
import urllib

for line in open('file.txt', 'r').readlines():
left, right = string.split(line, maxsplit=1)
relation = string.split(line, maxsplit=1)

le = relation[0]
ri = relation[1]

le = urllib.unquote(relation[0])
le = le.replace('_', ' ')


print le, '\t', ri
```

Comment: You should not use string.split(). Each string object provide the split() method *directly*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restrain your split.

```
left, right = line.split(None, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `split` method splits string by any whitespace.  To split string by a tab, pass extra parameter to this method:

```
left, right = line.split('\t', 1)
```

Comment: I thought they split by whitespace, rather than " "

Comment: @samb8s well, yes, by any white-space.

Comment: @Roman Bodnarchuk: Please give details.Still getting error `need more than 1 values to unpack`

Comment: @Roman Bodnarchuk: questions updated.Also, tried with your updated, still getting error.

Comment: @Blue it looks like you are still using your original version of `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

```
left, delim, right = line.partition('\t')
```

Comment: @Blue Ice, if you're using Python older than 2.5, it's a good idea to mention it in the question/tags